# ClickOnce publish to file share tries to create a web site location

Tags: c#, clickonce, fileshare

I am following the instruction to publish with ClickOnce to a file share as specified here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey(v=VS.100).aspx

In the section titled "To publish to a file share" I did the following:

```
1.In Solution Explorer, select the application project
2.On the Build menu, click Publish Projectname
3.In the Where do you want to publish the application? page, enter a valid file path using the format
4.In the How will users install the application? page, select the location where users will go to install the application
    I selected From a UNC path or file share
5.On the Will the application be available offline? page, click the appropriate option
    I selected Yes, this application will be available online or offline
6.Click Finish to publish the application
```

when I follow these instructions verbatim, I get the following error:

```
Failed to connect to '\\myserver\myshare\myproject\myprojecPublish\' with the following error: Unable to create the Web site '\\myserver\myshare\myproject\myprojecPublish'.  Unable to create the Web site location '\\myserver\myshare\myproject\myprojecPublish'.  Access is denied.
```

Why does it try to create a web site location when I'm trying to publish to a file share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No joy.  Had to abandon ClickOnce.